# How to check table size in VectorWise database

Tags: vectorwise

I want to check the size of a table in VectorWise.Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through terminal monitor:

```
sql mydb
help table mytable
```

VectorWise is just the modified Ingres RDBMS. All terminal monitor commands should work...